# Angular Trigger Div Click based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I need to disable click on certain divs based on some condition. Can anyone guide me please? Currently am using **ng-disabled** which is not working

Working Demo below for you to play

```css
.aw-right-pane-content{height:200px; width:200px;}
.aw-dataType-selected{background:green;}

.charts{
  height:30px; width:30px;
  border:1px solid #ccc; 
  margin:20px 0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="aw-right-pane-content" 
     ng-init="chartsOfSelectedDatatype=[{name:'Chart1',selected:false,clickable:false},   {name:'Chart2',selected:false,clickable:true},{name:'Chart3',selected:false,clickable:true},{name:'Chart4',selected:false,clickable:false}]">
       <div data-ng-repeat="chart in chartsOfSelectedDatatype" class="aw-right-pane-charts" >
          <div ng-click="chart.selected = !chart.selected" class="charts" ng-class="{'aw-dataType-selected':chart.selected}" ng-disabled = "chart.clickable"></div>
          <div class="aw-right-pane-charts-name"> {{chart.name}}</div>
        </div>

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the problem but `ng-disabled = chart.clickable` should be `ng-disabled ="chart.clickable"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable a div using `ng-disabled` the possible solutions are either you can add an `ng-class` for disabled elements with no cursor events or you can use a `fieldset` instead of div.

**First Solution** - Using `ng-class` and changing script handling clickable property

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .aw-right-pane-content {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    .aw-dataType-selected {
        background: green;
    }
    
    .charts {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
    }
    .disabled {
        opacity: 0.4;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="aw-right-pane-content" ng-init="chartsOfSelectedDatatype=[{name:'Chart1',selected:false,clickable:false},   {name:'Chart2',selected:false,clickable:true},{name:'Chart3',selected:false,clickable:true},{name:'Chart4',selected:false,clickable:false}]">
    <div data-ng-repeat="chart in chartsOfSelectedDatatype" class="aw-right-pane-charts">
        <div ng-click="(chart.clickable)? chart.selected = !chart.selected : chart.selected = chart.selected" class="charts" ng-class="{'aw-dataType-selected':chart.selected, 'disabled': !chart.clickable}"></div>
        <div class="aw-right-pane-charts-name"> {{chart.name}} - {{chart.clickable}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Second Solution**. Using `fieldset` instead if div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .aw-right-pane-content {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    .aw-dataType-selected {
        background: green;
    }
    
    .charts {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="aw-right-pane-content" ng-init="chartsOfSelectedDatatype=[{name:'Chart1',selected:false,clickable:false},   {name:'Chart2',selected:false,clickable:true},{name:'Chart3',selected:false,clickable:true},{name:'Chart4',selected:false,clickable:false}]">
    <div data-ng-repeat="chart in chartsOfSelectedDatatype" class="aw-right-pane-charts">
        <fieldset ng-click="chart.selected = !chart.selected" class="charts" ng-class="{'aw-dataType-selected':chart.selected}" ng-disabled="!chart.clickable"></fieldset>
        <div class="aw-right-pane-charts-name"> {{chart.name}} - {{chart.clickable}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I will prefer the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
<div class="aw-right-pane-content" 
 ng-init="chartsOfSelectedDatatype=[{name:'Chart1',selected:false,clickable:false},   {name:'Chart2',selected:false,clickable:true},{name:'Chart3',selected:false,clickable:true},{name:'Chart4',selected:false,clickable:false}]">
  <div data-ng-repeat="chart in chartsOfSelectedDatatype" class="aw-right-pane-charts" >
      <div ng-click="chart.clickable ? chart.selected = !chart.selected: ''" class="charts" ng-class="{'aw-dataType-selected':chart.selected}"></div>
      <div class="aw-right-pane-charts-name"> {{chart.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ranakrrunal9, Thanks for your input. I need separate click handler as well to be attached

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a common `class` over elements that need not be clicked and apply `pointer-events: none;` to the same.

CSS should always be preferred in such cases instead of Javascript.